# Setting fill colors using hex value in ArcGIS Online (arcgis.com) webmap?

Tags: arcgis-online, color

Has anybody been able to use hex values (e.g. #FF0000) for setting polygon fill symbols in an ArcGIS Online (arcgis.com) 'webmap'?

I see predefined colors to select from, but no hex input box.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Online did not have an input for HEX codes previously, but you could always use websites like http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html to convert a HEX code you already know or a RGB combination you have on ArcGIS to find the HEX code.

However, as commented by @blord-castillo:

> ArcGIS Online now takes custom colors in hexadecimal notation. Click
>   on the polygon symbol and there will be a text box below the color
>   picker where you can enter a hex code. Not sure when this feature was
>   added.