# Symbolizing polygon fill color based on HTML hex color attribute value in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, symbology, attribute-table

I have a set of polygons that I need to symbolize with a certain color. I have an column in the attribute table that contains the contains the html hex color value (#FF0000 Red) that I want the polygon to be colored. Is there a way to symbolize the color based on the attribute value?

I see that this might be possible using ArcPy along with a .lyr file, but I am not very experienced with ArcPy, and the last post isn't that promising, stating that the symbology property is read-only.
[Using ArcPy to get layer symbology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/can-i-use-arcpy-to-get-layer-symbology)

This post is making me think that it's not possible.
[Changing color of symbol in UniqueValuesSymbology object using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/using-arcpy-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-symbol-in-a-uniquevaluessym)

Comment: Unfortunately, the post that you mention has not received a valid answer because it is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to use the hex color code as an attribute to automatically color code, but you can symbolize based on that column and color code based on that.

Unfortunately, you will have to look up the RGB color, as ArcMap does not use Hex Colors, unlike ArcGIS Online which now can - see [Setting fill colors using hex value in ArcGIS Online (arcgis.com) webmap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80221/how-can-i-set-fill-colors-using-hex-value-in-arcgis-com-webmap)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch to ArcGIS Pro, this is possible there:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/attribute-driven-symbology.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5E319812B4E14CEBAE02E002305EB0EA
(Note that ArcGIS Pro still has some cartographic limitations compared to ArcGIS for Desktop, such as a lack of frame indicators.)

Comment: Extent indicators are there now - came in at 1.1 - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/extent-indicators.htm